# Powershell - check if all users in a specific OU are disabled, disable if not

Tags: active-directory, powershell, user-accounts, users, organizational-unit

I tried to search for it but I didn't find anything. Could someone help me out with an example of a script that would do this?

Comment: As far as I know you can't lock them, but you can disable them.

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis i meant disable..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "ou=TheOU,dc=contoso,dc=com" | Disable-ADAccount
```

You might need to upgrade your Powershell version if it doesn't have the commands.

---

Try/Catch example:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "ou=TheOU,dc=contoso,dc=com"    

ForEach ($user in $users) {
    Try {
        Disable-Account
    }
    Catch {
        Write-Output "$($user) is already disabled."
    }
    Finally {
        # Cleanup tasks, etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: It disables all accounts, if they are already disabled then it will probably show an error. If errors are undesired, you can put the command in a `Try {} Catch {}` block, I'll show you how.

Comment: the script disables every account and DOES check to see which accounts are disabled

Answer (score 2):

To avoid disabling disabled accounts you can filter them out:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} -SearchBase "ou=TheOU,dc=contoso,dc=com" `
| Disable-ADAccount
```